# geom_points in ggmap not filling by variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm using the [Taiwan housing data found on UCI ML repository.](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Real+estate+valuation+data+set)

I'm trying to plot the houses on a map using ggplot, and fill the points with the house_price_unit_area. However, when I use fill = house_price_unit_area in the aesthetic call, it doesn't fill the points based on price, but rather it leaves them black.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Code included below, as well as a screenshot of what is produced.

[image]

```
library(ggplot)
library(ggmap)
library(readxl)

df <- read_xlsx("data/real_estate.xlsx")
df$No = NULL
colnames(df)= c("trans_date",
                "house_age",
                "distance_to_nearest_mrt",
                "number_of_conv_store",
                "lat",
                "long",
                "house_price_unit_area",
                "id")

world <- map_data(database = "world", regions = "Taiwan")

ggmap(get_stamenmap(bbox = c(left = 121.4, right = 121.64, bottom=24.9,top=25.1),location = "Taiwan"))+
  geom_point(data =df, mapping = aes(x=long,y=lat, fill = house_price_unit_area))+
  scale_fill_viridis_b()
```

Comment: Have you tried the `colour` aesthetic instead of `fill`?

Comment: I thought I did, but apparently I didn't as @Claudio demonstrated that works.

Answer (score 1):

I switch the `fill` argument for `col` and got this:

```
library(ggplot)
library(ggmap)
library(readxl)

df <- read_xlsx("Real estate valuation data set.xlsx")
df$No = NULL
colnames(df)= c("trans_date",
                "house_age",
                "distance_to_nearest_mrt",
                "number_of_conv_store",
                "lat",
                "long",
                "house_price_unit_area",
                "id")

world <- map_data(database = "world", regions = "Taiwan")

ggmap(get_stamenmap(bbox = c(left = 121.4, right = 121.64, bottom=24.9,top=25.1),location = "Taiwan"))+
  geom_point(data =df, mapping = aes(x=long,y=lat, col = house_price_unit_area))+
  scale_fill_viridis_b()
```

output:

[image]